# Filtering a collection with Linq and multiple criteria

Tags: vb.net, linq

On my view there is a datatable holding a collection of `ServerRow` and 4 textboxes (Hostname, OS, Location, Zone). When the user types into any of the 4 boxes I want to immediately filter this list. I have this code setup and ready to go that on the set method of each textbox property I call the filter method.

Now onto the problem: if I have 4 criteria that means I have 2 to the power of 4 different scenarios. What I would like to do is write a linq statement with all of these scenarios dealt with such that if any of the properties are `NullOrEmpty` they will not be used in the `Where` clause and on the flip side if there is a value the corresponding field will be searched with a `Contains`.

Example

```
AvailableCis = New ObservableCollection(Of ServerRow)
                (_CiData.Where(Function(ci) ci.OS.ToUpper
                .Equals(_selectedOS.ToUpper) AndAlso 
                ci.HostName.ToUpper.Contains(_ciNameFilterText.ToUpper))
                .OrderBy(Function(a) a.CiName))
```

This example shows how it works with 2 criteria and both of those criteria are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy evaluation to solve this problem -

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(ci.OS) OrElse ci.OS.ToUpper.Equals(_selectedOS.ToUpper)
```

This way if the string is null or empty the second clause is not evaluated and all ServerRows are accepted.

Also don't forget that AndAlso has a higher precedence than OrElse, so each clause has to be wrapped in brackets.